# MongoDB multiple date range groupings

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm storing data in hour buckets. Simplified structure:

```
{
    value: 20,
    date: ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00Z")
},
{
    value: 50,
    date: ISODate("2017-01-01T01:00:00Z")
},
{
    value: 90,
    date: ISODate("2017-01-01T02:00:00Z")
},
...
```

**Goal**

Make a single aggregate query to get all the month totals for the year. I cannot use the $month operator because I'm querying UTC data but desire local timezone groupings.

**Current Solution**

I can currently achieve this by making 12 separate queries like the following:

```
db.data.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        "date": {
            "$gte": ISODate("2017-01-01T08:00:00Z"),
            "$lte": ISODate("2017-01-31T08:00:00Z")
        }
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        "_id": "$date",
        total: {
            $sum: "$value"
        }
    }
}
])
```

*Note: Notice the 8-hr offsets to get the groupings in PST*

That would get me the total for January, but then I would need to make an additional query for every other month with different match conditions.

Comment: You just need to group data by month. Something like this `db.data.aggregate([
{
    $group: {
        "_id": { $month: "$date" },
        total: {
            $sum: "$value"
        }
    }
}
])`

Comment: Sorry, I made my question more clear. I cannot use the $month operator because I'm querying UTC data but desire local timezone groupings